# Merge two objects that contains the same ID and return one object with the properties

Tags: java, sql, spring, spring-boot, hibernate

```
class Item{
    Integer ID;
    String name;
    Double price;
}


class Item discount{
    Integer Id;
    Double discount
}
```

I have these two classes with a list of items on both and I am trying to return a new object "ItemWithDiscount" that has the attributes of both classes, this in a service/controller requisition. I tried mapping them with stream but wasn't able to do so. Can anyone give me a light of some way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not sure what you mean by 'mapping them with stream'...

You need to have some sort of combined object which can store all of the relevant properties. In pure object model design I would first think of a composite pattern, something like:

```
class ItemWithDiscount {
  public Item;
  public Discount;
}
```

Although you might want to consider immutability, etc. Now, if you are going to serialize this to JSON, for example, it might be easier to simply implement it as a class containing all the fields of the sub-objects in a flat form:

```
class ItemWithDiscount {
  public Integer itemId;
  public String name;
  public Integer price;
  public Integer discount;
}
```

and now you can create a constructor which does the flattening. This second design is a bit clunkier in some respects, but for most purposes it will work OK.

NOW you could potentially use stream syntax to build these composites, etc.